# Pandas remove rows based on presence of another row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large DF and I'd like to remove some redundant rows.

The DF is as follows:

```
A   B    C
foo 12   *
foo 12   z <- redundant row
foo 12   x <- redundant row
foo 15   x
bar 13   z
bar 13   x
```

I'd like to remove the rows for which another row exists with the same values, except with column C as "*".

So, the resulting df would be:

```
A   B    C
foo 12   * <- kept because it is the "foo 12" row that has the "*"
foo 15   x <- kept because there is no "foo 15 *" row
bar 13   z <- kept because there is no "bar 13 *" row
bar 13   x <- kept because there is no "bar 13 *" row
```

I'd like to avoid a cartesian product / merging the df with itself, if at all possible, for memory usage concerns.
(though if it's impossible, the df can be split and re-assembled)

Comment: Why are both `bar 13` kept? The "*" is all inclusive?

Comment: The last row in your final output is it not duplicate?

Comment: have you tried `.drop_duplicates()`? `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'],keep='first')`

Comment: Btw seems like you need - > `df[~df.duplicated(subset= ['A', 'B'])]`

Comment: The bar 13 are kept because there is no "bar 13 *". I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try keeping only rows that are `*` in groups with a `*` or else keep all rows:

```
s = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform(lambda c: c.eq('*').any())
df = df[df['C'].eq('*') | ~s]
```

`df`:

```
     A   B  C
0  foo  12  *
3  foo  15  x
4  bar  13  z
5  bar  13  x
```

---

Find groups of `A` and `B` with a `*` in `C`

```
s = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform(lambda c: c.eq('*').any())
```

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: C, dtype: bool
```

Find `*` in `C`:

```
df['C'].eq('*')
```

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: C, dtype: bool
```

Then `or` and negate:

```
df['C'].eq('*') | ~s
```

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: C, dtype: bool
```